# How do I fix a converting to parameter 2 error in python curses?

Tags: python, python-3.4, curses, cpython, python-curses

I was working in Unicurses, a cross platform module of curses for python. I was trying to put the '@' character in the center of my console. My code was this:

```
from unicurses import *
def main():
    stdscr = initscr()
    max_y, max_x = getmaxyx( stdscr )
    move( max_y/2, max_x/2 )
    addstr("@")
    #addstr(str(getmaxyx(stdscr)))
    getch()
    endwin()
    return 0
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

I kept getting the error

```
ctypes.ArgumentError was unhandled by user code
Message: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: Don't know how to convert parameter 2
```

for this line:

```
move( max_y/2, max_x/2 )
```

Does anyone know the cause and fix for this error. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure about `unicurses`, but I'm pretty sure that in `curses`, `move()` is not a module-level function, but rather a window method. In your case, it would mean `stdscr.move(...)`

Comment: @Lav, in unicurses `move` is module level. See the readme in https://github.com/Chiel92/unicurses. The window variant is `wmove`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're passing floats to the `move` function, while you should pass integers. Use the integer division operator `//` instead of `/`.

```
from unicurses import *
def main():
    stdscr = initscr()
    max_y, max_x = getmaxyx( stdscr )
    move( max_y//2, max_x//2 ) # Use integer division to truncate the floats
    addstr("@")
    getch()
    endwin()
    return 0
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I didn't know floor division could be used in that way. Another way would be to do the division and then use the int() function. Thanks!